# How to use a NN in a keras generator?

Tags: keras, generator

I am setting up a fit_generator to train a DNN by keras. But don't know how to use a CNN inside this generator.

Basically, I have a pre-trained image generator using fully-connected convolutional networks (we can named it as GEN-NET). Now I want to used this Fully-CNN in my fit_generator to generate unlimited number of images to train another classifier (called CLASS-NET) in keras. But it always crashed my training and the error message is:

> ValueError: Tensor Tensor("decoder/transform_output/mul:0", shape=(?, 128, 128, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

This "decoder/transform_output/mul:0" is the output of my CNN GEN-NET.

So my question is that can I use CNN based GEN-NET in my fit_generator to train GLASS-NET or it is not permitted in keras?

Comment: Can you explain better the problem and the setup? I am not sure I understand what you mean by: "I have trained an image generator".

Comment: The image generator is a fully connected CNN (composed by encoder-decoder) that can produce images. In my project, I used this image generator to transform some input images to another type of images. And want to use these transformed images to train another DNN based classifier.

Answer (score 1):

Keras does not really like running two separate models in a single session. You could use `K.clear_session()` after using the model but this would produce a lot of overhead!

Best way to do this, IMHO, is by pre-generating these images and then loading them using a generator. Basically splitting your program into two separate programs.

Otherwise, if you are using `tensorflow` as back-end there might be a way to do it by switching the default graph on the `tf.Session`, you could Google that but I would not recommend it! :)

Comment: Thanks.

I create a new graph session for the image generator and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might have things a bit mixed up! The CNN (convolutional neural network) needs to be trained to your data, unless you're using a pretrained network for predictions. If you're going to train the CNN, you can do that with either the `fit()` or the `fit_generator()` function. Use `fit()` if you're feeding data directly, and use `fit_generator()` if your data is handled by [Image Data Generators](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). If you've loaded a pre-trained model/weights only to make predictions, you don't need to use any fit function, since no training needs to be done.

Comment: Actually I have two networks. One is a pre-trained CNN based generator, which can produce sort of images. Another one is a CNN based classifier which is going to be trained.

So what I want to do is to use this CNN based generator in fit_generator to produce images and use these images to train my second CNN based classifier.

Comment: Ahh. Seems like you could train the first CNN, freeze it, then connect its output to the input of your next network, and fit_generator() that, perhaps? Something like this: `second_model_x = first_model.layers[-1]` as input layer of your second model, then `second_model = Model(input=first_model.layers[0].input,output=second_model_x)` or similar.